# Edge Bevel Weirdness

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, bevel

I was working on a model when I encountered this problem while trying to bevel an edge. I'm not sure what's causing this even after I've tried merging duplicate vertices and applying the scale. If anyone knows what might be causing this issue, I'd love to know why this is happening.

Thanks!

[image]

Edit: As per Allen's suggestion, I've added a simplified version of the model with the problem edges marked with red seams. They don't exactly replicate the GIF I've posted, but I think it's a similar problem nonetheless.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to BSE!  It's hard to tell exactly what's happening but it appears to be a geometry issue.  Can you post a file containing the minimum required to reproduce this issue at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit your question to include the download link they provide?  You can start a new file and go to *File -> Append* to bring this mesh into the new file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you have some faces pointing inwards and some pointing outwards. You can tell by turning on *Face Orientation* and *Face Normals* in  **Overlays**:

[image: Direction1]

To fix it, select the whole thing in edit mode and then select *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*. You can now bevel as you wish:

[image: Direction2]

Comment: Thanks Chris!
This was exactly the problem.